# SignalR HubProvider.Connection.Start() is taking about 60 second

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an ASP.NET.Core server which uses Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR(2.2.1) for communication to WPF client. Because I use AspNet.SignalR and AspNet.SignalR.Owin on server side I host this app like a Kestrel console application. This application has been hosted on 3 different servers and there are problems with the servers hosted on Amazon EC2. First connection (running Connection.Start() method) takes a lot of time(about 60 seconds!!!). Invokes hub's method and requests to the controller working with normal speed. I tried to research this, of course I configured security group and firewall for HTTP traffic, but I really have no idea what is going on. Has anyone else had this problem? Does Amazon use any network monitor for EC2?

**Update**
Oh vey. I understand. Problem is much logic in OnConnected() hub method. All is OK but some my services on amazon start very slow. Thank you!

Comment: Start from turning on traces and looking at the HTTP requests the client is sending and how long it took to process them. If you have any code on the server side that runs when the connection is being established (authorization, OnConnected etc.) look at these.

Comment: @Alex Olshansky: Maybe it will help you to define the transport to a specific mechanisme. For example take LongPolling for testing: await hubConnection.Start(new LongPollingTransport()); 
 Defails you will find on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Comment: @Pawel OnConnected() execute after 60-70 seconds after start of client. I tried start client on server rdc - result the same.

Comment: @Tester I tried to use long polling and server sent events transports. I didn't see speed difference.

Comment: Do you do anything on the server before the connection is started (like auth, adding a connection to a group etc.?)